# Have ngRepeat stop after one cycle, using in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get some more information about the van, by using its id to call the fleet that it is attached to. My code works right now when I return information about the van. But when I un-comment the commented lines of the code it breaks, and gives me this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Why is it that I can't call a service, I don't understand why that breaks it, or how to fix it.

Directives.directive('displayCurrentVans', ['Van', 'Fleet', function(Van, Fleet) {

```
var render =   '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-lg-12">' +
        '<div class="alert alert-info alert-bottom-trimmer">' +
            '<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive text-center">' +
                '<thead ng-click="renderVans()" class="cursor">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<th class="text-center">Van</th>' +
                        '<th class="text-center">Radio</th>' +
                        '<th class="text-center">User</th>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</thead>' +
                '<tbody ng-show="vanbox" ng-repeat="van in vans | limitTo: 4">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td>{{getVan(van)}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{van.radio}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{van.user_id}}</td>' +
                   '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
            '</table>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

return {
    scope: true,
    compile: function(tElem, atts){
        tElem.append(render);
        return function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.vans = Van.GetVans();
            scope.fleet = Fleet.GetFleets();

             console.log(Fleet.GetFleet({id: '1'}));

            scope.vanbox = false;
            scope.renderVans = function(){
                console.log("hello");
                scope.vanbox = !scope.vanbox;
            }
            scope.getVan = function(van){
              console.log("hi");
              return van.id
              //var number = Fleet.GetFleet({id: van});
              //return number.ident;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

1- you're not supposed to use CamelCase in directive Names(though this is not your current problem);

2- in your code , after : "return van.id"  , you connot write more codes , I mean , thats a rule , after using return , dunction will break and ends So you connot write any more codes after your first **return**

```
         return van.id
          **No more codes here, because your function ends here**
            So below lines will never excecute
          //var number = Fleet.GetFleet({id: van});
          //return number.ident;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out direvtive names, I didn't know that. 

Also, I should have clarified about the commented code, when I un-comment it I also comment out the first return statement. I was just experimenting because with a return statement of van.id it works, but when I comment that out and make a call to a service it breaks.